# How to implement YOLO in my CNN model?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras, cnn, yolo

I build a CNN model using keras on the cat vs dog dataset. Now what I want is with the image classification my model should also locate that animal on that image. I searched on web and found that YOLO is used for object localization, but when I looked up some codes on github I didn't understand how to implement it with my model.

I have a simple CNN model on keras and I want to localized the animal. If someone has other suggestion please do give them.